# Is there a closed curve with constant radius of curvature？

Tags: differential-geometry

Is there a closed curve with constant radius of curvature？

Circle is an answer. Is there some other solution in 3D?

Comment: Good question, bad presentation. Question body should not be a continuation of the question title.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309531/closed-space-curves-of-constant-curvature

Comment: Coiling a curve around a torus ought to work.